# how to stop websphere profile from starting as windows service

Tags: windows-services, websphere, websphere-8

Right now my websphere profile starts/stops as windows service. However I want it to be started/stopped using the batch script as below:

```
<WebSphere Path>\AppServer\profiles\<Profile name>\bin\startServer.bat server1
<WebSphere Path>\AppServer\profiles\<Profile name>\bin\stopServer.bat server1
```

Is there a way to do this without deleting and recreating a new profile?
I am using WAS version 8.5.1 on windows 7 environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the InfoCenter topic for the [WASService](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rins_wasservice.html) command:

```
WAS_HOME\bin\WASService.exe -profilePath c:\path\to\profile -remove server_name
```